# How to Get Path to Native Binaries that are part of nuget package in dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package, .net-core

I'm looking to use phantomjs in a aspnet core application.  I want to package the phantomjs binary (platform specific) as a nuget package and then essentially be able to call process.start on it from within the app.

The documentation on this scenario seems pretty non-existent as most are focused on native libraries and dllimport.  I know I can just package/copy the file with my app, but would prefer to package it.

My package copies the binaries to the runtime folders on publish, but how do I get the runtime location of the binary? Was thinking something like RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory(), but this doesn't exist for core.

This could also be asked of how do you package runtime specific files that should be copied to output?